# Stripe customer management on android using ephemeral keys and volley

Tags: android, android-volley, stripe-payments

I am trying to achieve this on `stripe` (as shown in the image) on the `android SDK`. 
[image]
I have already created an endpoint on my server which returns the ephemeral key in this format

```
{
    "id": "ephkey_EPHEMERAL_KEY_HERE",
    "object": "ephemeral_key",
    "associated_objects": [
        {
            "id": "cus_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE",
            "type": "customer"
        }
    ],
    "created": 1535352558,
    "expires": 1535356158,
    "livemode": true,
    "secret": "ek_live_SECRET_HERE"
}
```

The `stripe` documentation here https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/standard is however not very clear on how to go about this on the android platform and I am totally lost and confused. I am using `volley` library for networking on the app. Any pointers on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that implements [`EphemeralKeyProvider`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/EphemeralKeyProvider.java) which will communicate with your backend to get the key. [Example here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/service/ExampleEphemeralKeyProvider.java).

You then use that class to instantiate a `CustomerSession`([example](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/activity/PaymentSessionActivity.java#L110-L119)), and finally create a `PaymentSession`([example](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/activity/PaymentSessionActivity.java#L140-L171)), which will use the `CustomerSession` you created to interact with the Stripe API(via the ephemeral key) to manage the customer's payment sources.

Comment: i followed your guide but now am getting "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stealthdroids.itransfer/com.stripe.android.view.PaymentMethodsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to get instance of CustomerSession without initialization." when i try to add a card

Comment: ""Attempted to get instance of PaymentConfiguration without initialization."

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing your code. You need to call `CustomerSesson.initCustomerSession` and `PaymentSession.init` like in the example code I linked to. It might be best to just run the Stripe example app first so you can play around with it and then adapt the parts you need. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android#example-apps

Comment: links are borken. Either update it or write the code here